# How to add Json Formatters to MvcCore?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm following the next [tutorial of IdentityServer4 implementation for API](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) , but I can't call the method `AddJsonFormatters()` to `services.AddMvcCore()`.
I'm currently configuring the API from an empty template in ASP.NET Core 3.0.0

I have added NuGet package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json` with no results.
Also, I understand that using `AddMvc()` instead of `AddMvcCore()` would be a partial solution but I can't use `AddAuthorization()` on `AddMvc()`

```
//code extracted from the link
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvcCore()
            .AddAuthorization()
            .AddJsonFormatters();
    }
}
```

This is the error message I see above:

> 'IMvcCoreBuilder' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddJsonFormatters' and no accessible extension method
>   'AddJsonFormatters' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IMVCoreBuilder' could be found (are you using a missing directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Is this the method? Should I send an MVCCoreBuilder? How do I do that? [MvcJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddJsonFormatters Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcjsonmvccorebuilderextensions.addjsonformatters?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Check the tutorial again, it has been updated to NetCore3. In short you don't need `AddJsonFormatters()` anymore so just remove it.

Answer (score 6):

When you call `services.AddMvc()` you get an `IMvcBuilder`.

if you want to add more output or input formatters, the `IMvcBuilder` has an extension method that you can call `AddMvcOptions` bellow you have an example of an `XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter` that was added

```
    mvcBuilder.AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
            options.InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter(options));
```

Mvc already has a `JsonOutputFormatter` ,so inside of the `AddMvcOptions` you can get it and also and add your own custom mediatypes if you need it.

```
var jsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (jsonOutputFormatter != null)
        {
            jsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(HttpMediaTypes.Vnd+json.all);
            jsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(HttpMediaTypes.ApplicationOctetStream);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

As I understood, there is not class `MvcJsonMvcCoreBuilderExtensions` in .NET Core 3.0 yet.

Eventually I just added `-f` parameter when I was created the **Api** project:

```
dotnet new web -n Api -f netcoreapp2.2
```

instead of

```
dotnet new web -n Api
```

It makes the **Api** project for .NET Core 2.2 so you can read the tutorial.

Comment: yeppp, i removed the sdk's higher than 2.2 from pc so it would build with 2.2 a new `dotnet new web` project

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I found that I was on the wrong tutorial for implementing it with the current versions of dotnet core. The comment made by -AnorZaken helped:

> Check the tutorial again, it has been updated to NetCore3

Look at the top of the sidebar on the tutorial page. If it says "Release" under the IdentityServer4 title, that won't work.

There is a dropdown at the bottom of the sidebar where you can select "3.1" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
If MVC

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
              new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
.....
.....
```

if it is API than use

```
 services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewton ......
```